# How to fix scrape web table output csv with python and bs4

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

Help me please,,
I want to take 2 data in "td", "Barcode" and "nama produk" but I get very bad data. what should I fix?

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


outfile = open("dataaa.csv","w",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)


page = 0
while page < 3 :
    url = "http://ciumi.com/cspos/barcode-ritel.php?page={:d}".format(page)
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    page += 1
    table_tag = tree.select("table")[0]
    tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("tr")]
    for row_data in table_tag.select("td")]
    for data in tab_data:
        writer.writerow(data)
        print(table_tag)
        print(response, url, ' '.join(data))


import fileinput
seen = set() 
for line in fileinput.FileInput('dataaa.csv', inplace=1):
    if line in seen: continue

    seen.add(line)
    print (line)
```

What do I need to improve to get beautiful results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pages start from 1 so my range loop starts there. Then you can use [Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object for efficiency of re-using connection. If you choose your css selectors wisely all filtering can be done at that level and you then only work with the required elements retrieved. You can use more lightweight `csv` rather than heavier `pandas` import.

Requires **bs4 4.7.1+** as leverages `:has` pseudo selector.

---

**Quick explanation:**

The following selects the first column barcodes by targeting only `center` elements with [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) `center`

```
soup.select('center')
```

Then

```
soup.select('td:has(center) + td')
```

selects for the second column by using [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to get the right hand side adjacent table cell next to the left hand side table cell (td) which has `center` child element.

The retrieved tag lists have their `.text` extracted, and stripped, within list comprehensions and then these are zipped and converted to a list again; and appended to final list `results` which is later looped to write out to csv.

The css selectors are kept minimal to allow for faster matching.

---

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

results = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1,4):   #pages start at 1 and assuming you actually want first 3
        r = s.get(f'http://ciumi.com/cspos/barcode-ritel.php?page={page}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        results += list(zip([i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('center')] , [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('td:has(center) + td')]))

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['Barcode','Nama Produk'])
    for line in results:
        w.writerow(line)
```

---

**Additional reading:**

1. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify this with using pandas. Pandas uses BeautifulSoup under the hood to parse tables, by the way:

```
import pandas as pd

results_df = pd.DataFrame()
for page in range(1,3):
    url = 'http://ciumi.com/cspos/barcode-ritel.php?page=%s' %page
    results_df = results_df.append(pd.read_html(url)[0], sort=True)

results_df.columns = ['Barcode', 'Nama Produk']
results_df = results_df.reset_index(drop=True)

results_df.to_csv('dataaa.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results_df)
          Barcode                         Nama Produk
0   8992694242533             ZWITSAL SOAP 80G PACK 4
1   8992694247163         ZWITSAL SOAP 80G MILK&HONEY
2   8992694242502            ZWITSAL SOAP 80G CLASSIC
3   8992694245435  ZWITSAL SKIN GUARD LOT 100ML SPRAY
4   8992694246074               ZWITSAL SHP 600ML C&R
5   8992694242908             ZWITSAL SHP 50ML REBORN
6   8992694020025          ZWITSAL SHP 500ML REF AVKS
7   8992694246333           ZWITSAL SHP 500ML C&R REF
8   8992694246364              ZWITSAL SHP 300ML AVKS
9   8992694246319       ZWITSAL SHP 250ML REF CLEAN&R
10  8992694246357          ZWITSAL SHP 250ML REF AVKS
11  8992694242922            ZWITSAL SHP 200ML REBORN
12  8992694242915           ZWITSAL SHP 100ML CLASSIC
13  8992694246340              ZWITSAL SHP 100ML AVKS
14  8992694242601          ZWITSAL PWD 50G SOFTFLOWER
15  8992694244254               ZWITSAL PWD 50G FRESH
16  8992694242656         ZWITSAL PWD 500G SOFTFLORAL
17  8992694241055            ZWITSAL PWD 500G FRESH F
18  8992694244056        ZWITSAL PWD 300G SOFT FLORAL
19  8992694244513         ZWITSAL PWD 300G MILK&HONEY
```